# Setting variable value as button value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to dynamically change the value of a button with jquery

I am able to set a constant string dynamically with this

```
 $(".showdeal").html('New Users');
```

But when I store a value in a variable and set the button value to the variable value it doesnot work. I have tried these

```
var x=data.dealCount;
$(".showdeal").html(x);
$(".showdeal").html('x');
```

These two doesnot work. How can I set the value of the button to a variable value?

Comment: what is your data? ie) what is the value of x?

Comment: are you sure `data` is not empty?

Comment: data is a value from a JSON reply.

Comment: @AravindKumar Show the value of data?

Comment: @Shree Yes I am sure its not empty

Comment: @user1671639 here data has the value 4. An integer value. To be more clear it is 'data.dealCount' - a value from a JSON reply and its not empty

Comment: if `data` is of type object then nothing will be displayed

Comment: @AravindKumar It will work, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wxsd8/1/.  Possible to update your code in that?

Comment: Is it `input[type="button"]` or `button`

Comment: @AkhilSekharan It is a button not input[type="button"]

Comment: I think your data is empty because if it is not empty $(".showdeal").html(x) will work. Are you using firebug? there might be an error in your code

Comment: @user1671639 It works with normal datatypes like integer. But when I try to use a value from a JSON reply like data.showDeals it doesnot work

Comment: maybe you're not parsing your JSON . I think the question should be about parsing json not passing values to buttons

Answer (score 0):

If your "showdeal" class is applied to a button then why dont you use the val() on button for setting its value.

I would write it as

```
var x=data.dealCount;
$(".showdeal").val(x);
```

try if this works ?

as of i know html() returns/sets the contents between the tag so...

sry for pre code ..

try this ..

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var x=data.dealCount;
$(".showdeal").html(x);
```

Comment: From his comments[ It is a button not input[type="button"]], he mentioned he used `button` tag.  so I think this wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works good.  But incase you may made a mistake in parsing your JSON, try using [**.parseJSON()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

**HTML:**

```
<button class="showdeal"></button> <!-- As you mentioned in comments -->
```

**JS:**

```
var data =  {dealCount: '4'}
var x = data.dealCount;
$('.showdeal').html(x);
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxsd8/3/)

Comment: @Aravind Kumar: let us try this, add this `console.log(data.dealCount);` before your `x` and share it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
 <body>
  <input type='button' value='' id='button'/>
  <script>
var x='clickme';//you can assign any dynamic value here
  $('#button').val(x)
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) data?

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);
$(".showdeal").html(data.dealCount);
```

try **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/gfRbx/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use "val" instead of "html"

```
 $(".showdeal").val(x);
```

And this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='button' value='Submit' id='btn1'>
$("#btn1").attr('value', 'JSON VAL');  //versions older than 1.6

<input type='button' value='Add' id='btnAddProfile'>
$("#btn1").prop('value', 'JSON VAL'); //versions newer than 1.6

$("#btn1").html('JSON VAL'); // for different buttons
```

I have set up a fiddle please [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Akash619/Q4ydJ/), play along with the version and see what works with the version you are using.